# nginx multiple static content servers on subdomains

Tags: nginx

I have one server with nginx-frontend and Apache-backend.

I need to set up nginx to return images from the other two servers
randomly like

- `http://example.com/images/*.jpg` -> `http://i1.example.com/*.jpg`
- `http://example.com/images/*.jpg` -> `http://i2.example.com/*.jpg`

image folder is the same on both servers.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: So you have 3 servers?

Comment: Yes. in total 3 servers.

Comment: It's unclear what you want.

Comment: Do you want to basically load balance between the two image servers? So first request goes to `i1.example.com` and next request goes to `i2.example.com` or when you say random you want it to get a random file from those to locations?

Comment: first request goes to i1.example.com and next request goes to i2.example.com

Comment: proxy_pass and upstream

Answer (score 0):

You would use the upstream directive to do this.

Sample below, you would add in the rest of your server config etc

```
upstream backend {
    server i1.example.com;
    server i2.example.com;
}

location /images/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
    #rest of config
}
```

It is possible to do more then 50/50 split by using the weight function but without it the default weight is used which is 1.

[Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

Comment: This is for anything in the `/images/` directory, if you want just `jpg` it would need a small adjustment

Comment: anything in the /images/

Comment: @garrykiev Then this will do it

Comment: @Drifter104, fixed code.

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks, I normally forget the `;` not the `/`